# How do you use canvas as a class?

Tags: javascript, class, object, canvas

I am trying to create a class which has a canvas as an object in an attempt learn more about classes. I wrote the following code but it gives nothing but a blank screen.

```
    class Canvas
{
    constructor(canvasId = 'canvas', dimension = '2d', canvasWidth = document.body.clientWidth,canvasHeight = window.innerHeight,canvasDisplay = 'block',canvasOverflow = 'hidden')
    {
        // Initialize Canvas and Context variables
        this.can = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        this.ctx = this.can.getContext(dimension);
        //  Set canvas properties
        this.can.width = canvasWidth;
        this.can.height = canvasHeight;
        this.can.style.display = canvasDisplay;
        this.can.style.overflow = canvasOverflow;
        this.count = 0;
    }

    display(ctx) 
    {
        var ctx = ctx;
        var scrollSS = new Image();
        scrollSS.src = "../../../Assets/Media/Images/Scroll/ScrollSpriteSheet.png";
        ctx.drawImage(scrollSS,0,0,102,345,10,0,canvas.width / 10,canvas.height);
    }

    animate(ctx) 
    {   
        var ctx = ctx;
        console.log(this.count);
        this.count++;
        this.display(ctx)
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate(ctx));   
    }


}

var canvas = new Canvas();
console.log(canvas.ctx);
canvas.animate(canvas.ctx);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling `animate()` again and again within your `requestAnimationFrame()` method. You instead need to let JS call the function `animate` for you when requestAnimationFrame() decides to do so.

This means you need to pass the `animate` function into `requestAnimationFrame`, not the actual function *call* (because when you call the function, you're really passing through its *return* value):

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
```

Since JS will handle the calling of the `animate` method, the `this` inside of `animate()` (when invoked) will not be your `Canvas` object, but rather the `window`. To make `this` refer to your `Canvas` object you'll need to `.bind(this)` to your `animate` function. The above is equivalent to using an arrow function:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
```

Your other issue is that you're trying to display the image before it has loaded. You firstly need to load the image and then display it. If your image is going to stay the same, I recommend you load it before you draw, rather than loading it every time you want to redraw (see second code snippet).

Also, `ctx` is part of your canvas instance. Each canvas object will have a `.ctx` property as it is defined in the constructor. So, there is no need to pass it through as an argument to `animate` or `display`, as you can access it by using `this.ctx`.

See example below (note the image is a temporary image):

```js
class Canvas {
  constructor(canvasId = 'canvas', dimension = '2d', canvasWidth = document.body.clientWidth, canvasHeight = window.innerHeight, canvasDisplay = 'block', canvasOverflow = 'hidden') {
    // Initialize Canvas and Context variables
    this.can = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    this.ctx = this.can.getContext(dimension);
    //  Set canvas properties
    this.can.width = canvasWidth;
    this.can.height = canvasHeight;
    this.can.style.display = canvasDisplay;
    this.can.style.overflow = canvasOverflow;
    this.count = 0;
  }

  display() {
    var ctx = this.ctx;
    var scrollSS = new Image();
    scrollSS.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRha_-J-uQR_8pUrUQOiPYZ_JXRoqfoqDt8BO8icSfkworyz9woQQ&s";
    scrollSS.addEventListener('load', e => {
      ctx.drawImage(scrollSS, 0, 0, 102, 345, 10, 0, this.can.width / 10, this.can.height);
    });
  }

  animate() {
    this.count++;
    this.display();
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }
}

var canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Here is an approach using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that you might want to take if you only need to load the one image:

```js
class Canvas {
  constructor(canvasId = 'canvas', dimension = '2d', canvasWidth = document.body.clientWidth, canvasHeight = window.innerHeight, canvasDisplay = 'block', canvasOverflow = 'hidden') {
    // Initialize Canvas and Context variables
    this.can = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    this.ctx = this.can.getContext(dimension);
    //  Set canvas properties
    this.can.width = canvasWidth;
    this.can.height = canvasHeight;
    this.can.style.display = canvasDisplay;
    this.can.style.overflow = canvasOverflow;
    this.count = 0;
  }

  loadImage(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        resolve(this);
      });
    });
  }

  display(img) {
    var ctx = this.ctx;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 102, 345, 10, 0, this.can.width / 10, this.can.height);
  }

  animate(img) {
    this.count++;
    this.display(img);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this, img));
  }
}

var canvas = new Canvas();
var img_url = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRha_-J-uQR_8pUrUQOiPYZ_JXRoqfoqDt8BO8icSfkworyz9woQQ&s"; 
canvas
  .loadImage(img_url)
  .then(function(image) {
    canvas.animate(image);  
  });
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank You for the help Nick Parsons. Learnt a lot .